# How to TRUNCATE 100 TABLES At a time in SQL

Tags: sql, database, truncate

I just want to delete the data not the structure.

Comment: Do you want to remove all data from 100 different tables, with just one statement? (Or do you want to remove 100 rows from one table...?)

Comment: I want to remove datat from all 100 different tables, with just 1 statement

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some of them have a TRUNCATE statement, others not...)

Answer (score 0):

Generate a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement for each table and execute it

You can do this is many ways, some of which are

- Use a loop and dynamic SQL
- Copy the table names to excel and use it to generate the statement

Comment: that means i use 100 time TRUNCATE  table query

Comment: @jiten yes, why is that a problem?

Comment: Problem is that How to get or copy 100 tables name at a time

Comment: @jiten Do you know which tables to delete? They are written down somewhere right? Copy them to excel, you can easily generate the TRUNCATE TABLE statements in excel and then paste in SQL to execute

Answer (score 0):

Generate a script.

Oracle example:

```
set head off
set pagesize 0
spool t.sql

select 'truncate table '||table_name||';' from all_tables
order by table_name
where rownum < 100
```

Or if SQL Server, or an ANSI approach is required, use sys.tables or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables

```
select top 100 
'truncate table ' + table_name + ';' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables;
```

MySQL

```
select CONCAT("truncate table ", table_name, ";")
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
limit 100;
```

Comment: ANSI SQL has FETCH FIRST, not TOP. (Newer Oracle versions also have FETCH FIRST.)

Comment: @jarlh - Thanks, but I was just giving platform specific examples, and just mentioned ANSI in regards to which dictionary table could be used. You are welcome to edit if you want to improve.